# How to call a function using GET Request in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to get a hang of Yii2 and learing it. I have now a quick question.

I have a function written in my `ProductController.php` called `actionGetPhoneForCustomer` with the parameter `$product`. The action calls another action within itself, that has an ActiveQuery in it. The query works great, the tests run where successful.

Now I want to have a simple GET request to call said function. However, it does not work properly. Am I writing the request wrong somehow? Below is the request I am trying to use and I always get a `404`Error. There really is no page needed, it's just a simple echo that should be returned. Below is the request as I am writing it.

`http://localhost:8080/myproductapp/web/index.phpr=product%2FgetPhoneForCustomer&product=Keyboard`

And this is the action:

```
public function actionGetPhoneForCustomer($product) {
        echo $this->getProductBySaleSatus($product);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something in the URL? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your url is wrong. You are missing question mark before GET params and you have to use kebab case for action: `get-phone-for-customer` if the name of method is `actionGetPhoneForCustomer`. So the url should look like this:
`http://localhost:8080/myproductapp/web/index.php?r=product%2Fget-phone-for-customer&product=Keyboard`

Comment: Oh man. I was trying wrong all the time. Thanks a lot. Care to explain why I need to use kebab case? I don't really get the idea why.

Comment: That's simply how Yii generates action's id from method name. It might've been done this way to avoid potential issues with case (in)sensitivity but that's just my guess.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, actually. Thank you very much for your time and your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Since you seem to know a lot about Yii2. Might I as another question? I am trying to get the values of a specific column in a table. I am using the following code. `User::find()->with('teamIdteams')->with('userHasTeams')->where('teamIdteams.name=:name')->addParams([':name' => $team])->all();`
But I allways get an error stating that the `teamIdTeams.name` column does not exist. I know it does exist however.

Comment: Using `with()` only tells `ActiveQuery` to use eager loading. That means that related models will be loaded during this query, but Yii internally uses another query to load them. If you want to reference column from related model you have to tell `ActiveQuery` to use JOIN. You can do that by using `joinWith()` method, for example `joinWith('teamIdteams')`. I don't use many-to-many relations that often so I don't know without testing if you have to explicitly include `userHasTeams` relation too but I think it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Also, you don't have to explicitly add params to query. You can simply use `where(['teamIdteams.name' => $team])` to add that condition. The framework will use the params properly for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really owe you one! Gonna see if I can make it work asap.